# Joining multiselect dropdown choices

Tags: c#, sql

I've got this code that will take all the selected items from a multi-select dropdown in C# and store them in a string:

```
var selectedQuery = ddlTrackingStatus.Items.Cast<ListItem>()
    .Where(item => item.Selected);

string txtSysDocChg = String.Join(",", selectedQuery).TrimEnd();
```

What I need to do is tweak this code so that all the selected items are stored with single quotes around them, so I can use the string in a `IN` statement in SQL Server. It keeps storing with the comma at the end when I try to do it.

Answer (score 1):

For the question `so that all the selected items are stored with single quotes around them`, here is the answer:

```
var selectedQuery = ddlTrackingStatus.Items.Cast<ListItem>()
    .Where(item => item.Selected);

string txtSysDocChg = String.Join(",", selectedQuery.Select(x => "'" + x + "'"));
//there should be no reason to keep the "TrimEnd()"
```

Remember that if your value already has single quotes in it, this will break.

However I think your problem is deeper, and has to do with how you are inserting your values.